# Nginx follow redirect and reverse proxy last location

Tags: redirect, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to reverse proxy an URL that have a N redirect 301 inside.
I want to follow all the pages and then reverse proxy the last page (fourth-url.php).

Is something douable with Nginx?

This is the scenario

FIRST URL:

http://first-domain.com/first-url.php

REDIRECT TO

http://first-domain.com/second-url.php

REDIRECT TO

http://first-domain.com/third-url.php

REDIRECT TO  (last one)

http://first-domain.com/fourth-url.php

This is the file configuration that I've made until now:

```
server {

  set $base_url 'http://first-domain.com';
  set $page 'first-url.php'

  location /myserver {
     resolver 8.8.8.8;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_pass $base_url/$page;
     proxy_intercept_errors on;
     error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
  }

  location @handle_redirect {
     resolver 8.8.8.8;
     set $saved_redirect_location $upstream_http_location;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_pass $base_url/$saved_redirect_location;
     proxy_intercept_errors on;
     error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirect;
  }
}
```

This should work as recursive function, but maybe I am missing an if statement or the last part.

Actually it works like this:

http://first-domain.com/first-url.php [OK]
http://first-domain.com/second-url.php [OK]

then nginx stop everything and return:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: unspecified
ERROR: Redirection (302) without location.
```

Side note: first-url.php, second-url.php, etc … contain just a simple line of code to make the redirect:

```
header("Location: second-url.php");
```

Any hints/ideas appreciated.

Comment: This question seems similar, though expanding it to 4 redirects would be pretty messy - the right solution in that case would be to rewrite the backend not to use quite so many redirects :)  https://serverfault.com/questions/423265/how-to-follow-http-redirects-inside-nginx

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Add recursive_error_pages directive.

```
server {
...
proxy_intercept_errors on;
recursive_error_pages on;
error_page 301 302 303 307 308 = @handle_redirect;
...
}
```

Additionally, according to [nginx recursion limited](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal), you do not have to worry about circular redirection problem since nginx set the recursion limitation to 10.